# How do I create a product with Amazon MWS api

Tags: amazon-mws

I just opened my seller account and i don’t know how to create a new product on amazon with MWS. Searched developer guide (http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_Overview.html) and cannot find anything about guide of creating product so i just looked into this explanation (https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf) and i found the title Create Product but i still don’t know how to create a product. The operation types always like ‘GetFeedSubmissionList’. So can anyone please explain in a descriptive way about creating a product. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read the guide that you mention above, "Selling on AmazonGuide to XML".  It goes through all the steps and includes examples.   You are going to want to study the Feeds API more specifically as that is the process to send products to MWS  http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_Overview.html

Comment: Hi @ScottG  thank u so much for answering. But for creating a product should i use the SubmitFeed operation?

Comment: Yes. Look at the feed types and format the feed with your product data

Comment: thanks a lot @ScottG. You're awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Feeds API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_Overview.html) and then set up your product with the correct [FeedType enumeration](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html) for the Product feed.  Look at the flowchart to understand the process involved.  You didn't specify a language or platform, but MWS has SDK's that will aid in your development.

Comment: The documentation link's not working anymore.

Comment: The links still work through the end of 2023 when they will be deprecated.